# Processing of .flv streamed to server via Wowza not always working (the file does not seem to be present in all cases)

Tags: flash, flv, wowza

I'm streaming a .flv to one of my web-servers via Wowza in order to get some recorded audio from the user.  Once the file is on the server I turn the audio into a .wav and do some other processing with it.

It seems to work well enough although sometimes I'll get an error on conversion which seems to be due to the file not being completely uploaded; or this is what I'm assuming anyway.  This is weird because I thought .flv was similar to other formats where you could process whatever you have at that point and don't need the end of the file.

Regardless... as a far from ideal test I looped the conversion attempt after waiting some time and it seemed to address 95% of the issues I was having.  I'm not a fan of this and was wondering if there is a way in Flash/Wowza to have it check for file upload completion before calling the server side conversion script.  I don't develop in flash so I've been kind of lost on this and hate the current method of looping after a set period of time to detect file existence.

Any suggestions and assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the file being continually streamed, or is it an all-at-once upload? What sort of error are you getting when you try to convert the file?

Comment: FLV is just a container format. It works according to whatever it holds, you never said what codec is the audio you're sending. Also it has the data broken into smaller chunks called tags so you still need a complete opened/closed data tag but not necessarily the complete file (unless the codec within requires it that way to decode properly). If you know its Flash calling the conversion function then ask your developer to check that the code does wait until all bytes uploaded before running this conversion. I'm not sure how Wowza would know how much bytes there should be anyway..?

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Sorry it took me song to respond.  

To @Houseman 's question: It is continually being streamed and the error I get when trying to convert with FFMPEG is:

 `code` 
/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine-4.0.1/content/114_5045_0.flv: could not find codec parameters 
`code`

To @VC.One Thanks for the info and I'll ask my developer to check that for me.  Thanks!

Comment: @Ron If the file is being streamed, you should wait until it's done streaming before trying to manipulate it with FFMPEG. Otherwise, you'll be processing an incomplete file, if you can even access it at all. Also, what FFMPEG command are you running?